# SQL Server 2000 backup recovering on SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000, database-backups

I've got a SQL Server database backup (file extension `.bak`) from an project of 12 y/a which I tried to restore on SQL Server 2005.

But this gave me an error that it was not the right version..

So I'm trying to find a SQL Server 2000 version to see if I can restore it with this but I can't find any version that works.

Is there another program to save my backup?

Comment: Maybe add the exact error you did receive...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied over from [msdn forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/d413a76e-aeff-40d1-aa9a-3d1801d408c7/):

1) Go to restore database

2) Select the database that you want to back up to

3) Locate the backup file on disk. You may have to put it into the MSSQL Server -> MSSQL.1-> MSSQL -> Backup Folder. It must be a .bak file.

4) Select the back that want to restore from the available  backups.

5) Go to the top left "options" property and when you do that select "overrite existing database".

6) Now make sure that the path to the files on database to be restored are correct in this same dialog view. Look at the paths to the database file and the log file and make damn sure that they are the correct ones for the database to be restored. The problem here is that those paths are going to be for the filesystem that the backup came from, not the one you are goning to put the restore onto.

Just to add to that, if you are restoring a database to a new server that does not have the database already in it (to restore to), create a sham database with the same name, then restore to it with the overwrite settings mentioned above.